# Apparent upward drift in pitch of "Mellow Piano" keytones on Roland HP 704

Tags: digital-piano, pitch

When I strike and hold any one of keys E4-G4 on my new Roland HP 704 in "Mellow Piano" setting, I hear an apparent upward drift in pitch of a semitone. When two adjacent keys are struck & held the beat note between them decays as expected, but the  upper note, a semitone higher, remains as it decays more slowly.
It therefore appears that the adjacent upper semitone is excited when the lower key is struck & then decays more slowly.
Is this endemic to the Roland HP 704? Can it be fixed?!

Comment: Best fix on your **new** Roland is to return it to the seller

Comment: Have you verified the drift of a single key by using a digital tuner or reference pitch? (Either are available as a mobile application.)  Also, check p. 18 of the manual.  Maybe it's the duplex scale setting (sympathetic strings.)